# Are the Surreals a cogenerator in the category of ordered fields?

Tags: ct.category-theory, surreal-numbers

A [cogenerator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cogenerator) in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is an object $\Omega$ such that for any pair of parallel arrows $f,g:X\rightrightarrows Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ we have

$$
\forall h:Y\to\Omega\big(h\circ f=h\circ g\big)\implies f=g,
$$

so morphisms into $\Omega$ are sufficient to delineate between distinct arrows. My question is

> Are the Surreals ${\bf N_0}$ a cogenerator in the category ${\bf \leq-Field}$ of ordered fields and ordered field homomorphisms?

Obviously we have some size issues here; I will offer one remedy below, but feel free to use whatever tools you like to get the surreals into a category.

> We will work in $ZFC+\text{there exist two}$ [Grothendieck universes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe) $U\subset V$, carying out our discourse in $V$ about the category ${\bf \leq-Field}_U$ of (possibly large in $U$) $U$-ordered fields. The surreals in $U$ are a weakly terminal object in this category; are they a cogenerator?

---

EDIT: To address some potentially confusing language that was initially pointed out by Pace Nielsen (thank you) and resolved in the comments below Kieth Kearnes' [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/390332/92164), by fields that are 'possibly large in $U$' I mean fields whose underlying classes are subclasses of $U$, not fields whose underlying classes are larger than all of $U$ or fields that are 'in $U$' in a membership sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On page 21 of

Conway's Field of Surreal Numbers
Norman L. Alling
Transactions of the American Mathematical Society
Jan., 1985, Vol. 287, No. 1, pp. 365-386.

one finds the statement that, on page 43 of

J. H. Conway, On numbers and games, Academic Press, London, 1976,

Conway states that  ``As an abstract Field, ${\bf N}_0$
is the unique universally embedding totally ordered Field.''

I don't have a copy of Conway's book, so don't know how he proved it.
If the claim is true, then it is sufficient to answer your question, since given distinct $f, g\colon X\to Y$ one can take an embedding $h$ of $Y$ into ${\bf N}_0$ to separate them.

**Edit** I am editing my answer to respond to the comments.

Originally I thought the main question was in the last sentence of the question: **The surreals in U are a weakly terminal object in this category; are they a cogenerator?**
The answer is affirmative, since in any category where all
morphisms are monic, any weakly terminal object is a cogenerator.

Now the comments lead me to think that I trivialized the problem. It seems to be this, instead: Given that every $U$-small ordered field embeds in ${\bf N}_0(U)$, does it follow that every $U$-large ordered field in $U$ embeds in ${\bf N}_0(U)$?

I say Yes in NBG with Global Choice. Let $\mathbb G$ be a $U$-large ordered field. Use Global Choice to enumerate $\mathbb G$ by the ordinals in $U$. For each cardinal $\lambda$, let $\mathbb G_{\lambda}$ be the
$U$-small ordered subfield of $\mathbb G$ generated by the elements enumerated by ordinals $<\lambda$. This yields a well-ordered (class size) filtration of $\mathbb G$. Starting with the embedding of $\mathbb G_0 = \mathbb Q$ into ${\bf N}_0(U)$, extend this embedding recursively to each ${\mathbb G}_{\alpha}$ using the following fact at successor stages:

**Fact.** Any embedding of $\mathbb G_{\alpha}$ into ${\bf N}_0$ can be extended to
$\mathbb G_{\alpha+1}$. This follows from the fact that ${\bf N}_0$ is a $\kappa$-universally extending model for all $\kappa$ (see An alternative construction of Conway's ordered field ${\bf N}_0$ by Philip Ehrlich, Algebra Universalis, 25 (1988) 7-16). Here I am relying on the fact that $\mathbb G_{\alpha}$ and $\mathbb G_{\alpha+1}$ are $U$-small in order to reference the $\kappa$-universally extending model property.

At limit stages take unions. I believe that this process yields a $U$-large embedding of $\mathbb G$ into ${\mathbf N}_0(U)$. Hence ${\mathbf N}_0(U)$ is weakly terminal even with respect to $U$-large ordered fields in $U$, hence is a cogenerator even for the class of $U$-large ordered fields in $U$.

Comment: The proof uses choice, correct? (probably in NBG?)

Comment: See related question https://mathoverflow.net/q/227849/1946 concerning whether one can prove the universality results without global choice. Seems to be an open question, even just for the order structure.

Comment: For what it's worth, IIRC (I do have ONAG but haven't read it in a while) the result about $\mathbf{No}$ being the unique universally embedding totally ordered field is one of many in the book that's stated without proof.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I realized yesterday that the next logical question was 'do we need choice/is this equivalent to global choice?', and then I remembered your question. Time for a bounty!

Comment: @AlecRhea Thanks!